# Scrollable element in flex container not working cross browser

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I've been tinkering around for most of today trying different solutions and I'm struggling to get something that works across browsers.

What I'm trying to create is 2 sections in a fixed div, the first with a static height and the second to fill the rest. Each of these will have a button to toggle their visibility, when the first is hidden then the second box will fill the entire space. This is working fine across browsers from what I can tell.

The problem is with the code in the second box, inside this, there will be a header, followed by a list, this will auto size but not shrink in the flex box, then another header which follows a second list, however with this list, I'd like it to be scrollable, this is where the problem I'm encountering seems to be.

As you can see in the first image, it seems to be working fine in Chrome and MS edge. However it seems to be playing up in firefox and Safari as it does not scroll, it just falls off the end of the page as you can see in the second image.

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be a great help!

[image]
[image]

```
html,body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
}

.container {
    position:fixed;
    top:32px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:220px;

    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    box-orient: vertical;
}

.container * {
    width:100%;
}

#box1 {
    background:green;  
    height: 220px;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -moz-box-flex: 0;
    box-flex: 0;
    border: 2px solid yellow;
}

#box2 {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-align-content: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: start;
    align-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-align: start;
    align-items: flex-start;

    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    box-flex: 1;
    border: 2px solid yellow;
}

.header {
    background:red;

    -webkit-flex: 0 0 24px;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 24px;
    flex: 0 0 24px;

    -webkit-align-self: auto;
    -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
    align-self: auto;
  }

  #list1 {
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
    flex: 0 0 auto;

    -webkit-align-self: auto;
    -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
    align-self: auto;

    background:orange;
  }

  #list2 {
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;

    -webkit-align-self: auto;
    -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
    align-self: auto;

    background:blue;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qNOxEj

Comment: I used table-rows in the end to get it to work in all browsers instead of flex :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start that work cross browser.

You need to add the prefixed flex properties for the older browsers you want to target.

```css
html, body{
  margin: 0;
}
.flex{
  display:flex;
}
.flex.column {
  flex-direction: column
}
.container{
  margin-top: 32px;
  height: calc(100vh - 32px);
}
.box {
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
}
.list1 {
  background-color: orange;
}
.list2{
  flex: 1;
  background: lightblue;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex column container">
  <div class="box">    
  </div>  
  <div class="list1">
    some header <br>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
    </ul>
    more text
  </div>
  <div class="list2">
    Bla bla<br>
    Bla bla<br>
    Bla bla<br>
    Bla bla<br>
    Bla bla<br>
    Bla bla<br>
    Bla bla<br>
    Bla bla<br>
    Bla bla<br>
    Bla bla<br>
    Bla bla<br>
    Bla bla<br>
    Bla bla<br>
    Bla bla<br>
    Bla bla<br>
    Bla bla<br>
    Bla bla<br>
    Bla bla<br>
    Bla bla<br>
    Bla bla<br>
    Bla bla<br>
  </div>
</div>
```